# How to enable future payments at the latest paypal checkout

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need a flow where I can login once to my web application with paypal to save it as a payment method, and I can process the payments every time the user clicks the purchase button without having to login at every purchase.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/ , paypal support provided me the following section but I can't find the flow I require.

Additional information:

- I plan to use laravel so I don't know if I would need the paypal php SDK.
- and in the front VueJS

Answer (score 0):

For Future Payments, also called Reference Transactions, the business owner of the PayPal account should contact their PayPal account manager or PayPal's general business support via https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us , to explain the business need for the feature